# Use only necessary fields in an object for URL params

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to cleanly grab some fields I need from an object.

The scenario is this:

I've got an object that is stored with certain 'extra' properties that exist because of the way we've set up our store in Redux. It'll look something like this:

```
var formData = { 
  account_name: 'SomeAccountName',
  custom_domain_name: '',
  id: 152
};
```

I'm trying to grab the fields I need from this object, which in this case are only `popup: true` and `account_name`, since `custom_domain_name` is empty. I'll be adding the necessary fields as params to the end of the URL.

What I've got so far works, but seems clunky to me. I was hoping I could do something with object destructuring, such as:

```
var fields = ['account_name']
var necessaryFields = { ...fields } = formData
```

But of course that doesn't work. This is what I've got instead:

```
//this turns an array of field objects into just the name of the field
const fieldNames = fields.map(field => field.key);

//so here I just grab the field name if it's not an empty string
//and stick it in the new object. `popup: true` is not a required
//field, but it is necessary for the URL.
let necessaryFields = fieldNames.reduce(
  (newFormObject, fieldName) => {
    if (formData[fieldName]){ 
      newFormObject[fieldName] = formData[fieldName]; 
    }
    return newFormObject;
  }, { popup: true });
```

After this code runs, I just run the object through an existing `addParamsToUrl` function (that unfortunately does not account for empty fields) that pretty much just does `field_name=field_value&` with each key-value pair.

Is there a nicer way to do this? I'm also always looking to make my code as functional as possible (and that's possibly why this irks me).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this in one go using `Object.keys` on your `formData` Object, followed by a few methods from the `Array` and `String` prototype.

```js
var formData = { 
  account_name: 'SomeAccountName',
  custom_domain_name: '',
  id: 152
};

var enc = encodeURIComponent;

// create an array from formData props
var query = Object.keys( formData )
// filter by the prop value length
// which will only give you props where the value
// has a length property which is greater than 0.
  .filter( key => formData[key].length )
// map to acctually add the value to the filtered props
// separated by equal signs.
  .map( key => enc( key ) + '=' + enc( formData[key] ) )
// add your popup prop
  .concat( 'popup=true' )
// join your array elements to a string separated by &.
  .join( '&' )
// finally add ? to the beginning of the string.
  .replace ( /^/,'?' );

// here is your query string.
console.log(query)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
```